# Single Sign On with Shibboleth IdP and Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I'm trying to setup a shibboleth IDP on Tomcat for SSO and I'm having some Tomcat configuration issues. I've followed the setup instructions in the Shibboleth website (https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPInstall). But I'm getting a 404 error saying that the idp resource I launched doesn't exist, even though I placed the idp.war (created during the shibboleth installation) in the webapps directory of tomcat. Going to the test URL provided by the setup instructions is how I found this issue (`https://idp.test.org/idp/profile/Status`  where idp.test.org is the tomcat server address).

I'm using an Amazon EC2 instance running 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,
Tomcat 6
and Shibboleth IDP 2.3.8

Answer (score 0):

Check the Tomcat console. If there is any exception missing some SAX classes during the deployment, you have to add them to the tomcat/lib folder to be able to run the war file. I do not understand why the hell they did not include them in the web-inf/lib folder...